# MSSQL get records from previous years where day and month smaller than current day and month

Tags: sql-server

On my invoice related query I have field called InvDate (the date of the invoice).  Invoice amounts needs to be compared to previous years up to the current day and month.  E.g. if today's date is 19 June 2018, I need the following records:

```
1 Jan - 19 June 2018
1 Jan - 19 June 2017
1 Jan - 19 June 2016
1 Jan - 19 June 2015
etc.
```

Comment: it will be more clear if you add your db schema

Comment: What do we do about leap years?

Comment: What is the exact output that you need? Are you looking for a summary row for each year?

Comment: For leap years the extra day can be included.  For the db schema there are two columns: invDate (Date) and invAmount (Decimal).  I need all the records, not only a summary.